# Integral of $m(\{x\in[0,1]:|f(x)|>t\})$ is finite

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Suppose $f\in L^p[0,1]$ for some $p$ with $1\le p\le\infty$. Define
>   $$h(t):=m(\{x\in[0,1]:|f(x)|>t\})$$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Show that $\int_0^\infty h(t)\; dt<\infty$.

My first thought was to try to use Chebyshev's inequality for finite $p$ as follows:
$$
\begin{split}
\int_0^\infty h(t)\; dt
 &= \int_0^\infty m(\{x\in[0,1]:|f(x)|>t\})\; dt \\
 &\le \int_0^\infty\frac1{t^p}
      \int_{\{x\in[0,1]:|f(x)|>t\}}|f(x)|^p\; dmdt
\end{split}
$$
And then use the fact that $f$ is in $L^p$ to bound the inner integral by some number $M_t$ dependent on $t$ which should go to 0 as $t$ goes to infinity. But this doesn't seem to be the way to go as it isn't clear how to integrate the resulting $\frac{M_t}{t^p}$ and even if I could, it's not obvious to me whether the result would be finite. In fact, it seems that it won't be unless $M_t\to0$ as $t\to0$.

So what other methods should I try at this point?

Comment: I think $\int_0^\infty h(t)dt = \int_0^1 |f(x)|dx$, which is finite by Hölder

Comment: @mathworker21 I can see how Hölder would finish the job, but could you elaborate on how you got that equality? I'm sure it's simple, but I can't see it.

Comment: Fubini on $1_{(t,\infty)}(|f(x)|)$.

Comment: @zbrads2 what copper said or just prove it for indicator functions, then simple functions, then measurable functions

Comment: Note that $\int_{t \ge 0} 1_{(t,\infty)}(|f(x)|) dt = |f(x)|$.